# Java RegEx not replacing all expected patterns

Tags: java, sql, regex

All I am trying to achieve is to replace comparative equals with ILIKE, but not assignment statements.

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE SUBJECT_TYPE = 'Person';
```

should be replaced as

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE SUBJECT_TYPE ILIKE 'Person';
```

However

```
SET session ABC.VAR = 5;
```

should remain untouched.

For this I am trying to use lookahead such that there is no **SET** before **equals (=)**.

**Java**

```
String str = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE SUBJECT_TYPE = 'Person' AND PREDICATE = 'name' AND OBJECT_VALUE = 'John' AND VERSION = '0' "
final Pattern EQUALS_ILIKE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?i)((^((?!SET)[^=])+?)\\s*)=");

final Matcher matcher = EQUALS_ILIKE_PATTERN .matcher(str);

while (matcher.find())
{
    final String fromString = matcher.group(0);

    str = matcher.replaceAll("$1 ILIKE");
}

System.out.println(str);
```

**Actual outcome:**

> SELECT * FROM db WHERE SUBJECT_TYPE  ILIKE 'Person' AND PREDICATE =
>   'name' AND OBJECT_VALUE = 'John' AND VERSION = '0'

**Expected outcome:**

> SELECT * FROM db WHERE SUBJECT_TYPE  ILIKE 'Person' AND PREDICATE
>   ILIKE 'name' AND OBJECT_VALUE ILIKE 'John' AND VERSION ILIKE '0'

The actual outcome here doesn't replace all necessary equals (=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a one-liner call to `String#replaceAll`:

```
 String str = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE SUBJECT_TYPE = 'Person' AND PREDICATE = 'name' AND OBJECT_VALUE = 'John' AND VERSION = '0' ";
str = str.replaceAll("(WHERE|AND)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+=(?=\\s*'[^'+]+')", "$1 $2 ILIKE");
System.out.println(str);
```

This outputs (formatted for readability):

```
SELECT *
FROM db
WHERE
    SUBJECT_TYPE ILIKE 'Person' AND
    PREDICATE ILIKE 'name' AND
    OBJECT_VALUE ILIKE 'John' AND
    VERSION ILIKE '0'
```

Comment: This regex won't take care of assignment thing i.e. the one which contains 'SET'.

Comment: Updated to target only the `WHERE` clause.  Now the `SET` clause won't be updated.

Comment: I am not really concerned about WHERE|AND , Just want to negate SET. Also I am wondering why my regex is not working for this ?

Comment: `(?!SET)` is a _zero width_ negative lookahead.  You never actually match any content after the lookahead, so it doesn't make much sense.  If you want a more robust solution, you would have to write a SQL parser, so I won't update my answer again.

Comment: would you like to update the answer with working solution at least ?

Comment: @Pratik My answer _does_ work, at least for the query you actually showed us.  If my answer fails for certain inputs, then edit your question and add those edge cases.